# What is the differences of outputs from set -o and set +o

Tags: set

When I use `set -o`:

```
❯ set -o
noaliases             off
aliasfuncdef          off
allexport             off
noalwayslastprompt    off
alwaystoend           on
appendcreate          off
noappendhistory       off
autocd                on
autocontinue          off
noautolist            off
noautomenu            off
autonamedirs          off
noautoparamkeys       off
...
```

When I use `set +o`:

```
❯ set +o
set +o noaliases
set +o aliasfuncdef
set +o allexport
set +o noalwayslastprompt
set -o alwaystoend
set +o appendcreate
set +o noappendhistory
set -o autocd
set +o autocontinue
set +o noautolist
set +o noautomenu
...
```

`set -o` uses on/off and `set +o` uses +o/-o.

I can see the similarity, but why it uses `+o/-o`?

Answer (score 0):

Some things are just because they are: some one decided that it would be that way.

```
If -o is supplied with no option-name, the values of the
current  options are printed.  If +o is supplied with no
option-name, a series of set commands  to  recreate  the
current  option  settings  is  displayed on the standard
output.
```

If you follow the `+o` or `-o` by an argument then the `-` and `+` have different meaning.